# Informal Version of 'Respectively'

Tags: word-usage, formality

When I say:

> The board and council meetings will be held on the 5th and the 6th of this month, respectively.

it seems to be the proper way to say it and it sounds correct . But when I say:

> Let's get tea and coffee for you and for me, respectively.

especially in an informal environment, it sounds unnatural at best and snobbish at worst. So what is a good informal word for 'respectively'?

Comment: There is nothing formal about *respectively*. A perfectly informal version of *respectively* is *respectively*.

Comment: The second sentence is just an awkward formulation. "Let's get tea for you and coffee for me" is more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let's get tea for you and coffee for me." this sound much more natural in friendly conversation.

Oops- that's exactly what Ryan Gell said! Upvoting his comment.